# How to simply the parameters when using a global std::array reference as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr, template-argument-deduction

This works in C++17:

```
template <std::size_t N, const std::array<int, N> & ARRAY> class Foo {};

constexpr std::array<int, 3> A{1, 2, 3};

void bar()
{
    Foo<3, A> foo_a;
}
```

So is there a way to avoid writing `N` in `Foo`'s template parameters? Since we could easily know it from `ARRAY.size()`. I tried this and failed:

```
template <template <size_t N> const std::array<int, N> & ARRAY> Foo {}; // Error.
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify the exact type of the reference. You can use a placeholder:

```
#include<array>

template <auto& ARRAY> class Foo {
    static constexpr auto N = ARRAY.size();
};

constexpr std::array<int, 3> A{1, 2, 3};

void bar()
{
    Foo<A> foo_a;
}
```

If you want to get an error if the template argument is not a reference to an `std::array<int, ...>`, you can write a type trait telling you whether the type is an instantiation of `std::array` and check the `value_type`:

```
#include<array>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename>
struct is_std_array : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_std_array<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_std_array_v = is_std_array<T>::value;

// std::remove_cvref_t will be part of C++20
template<typename T>
using remove_cvref_t = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

template<auto& ARRAY>
class Foo {
    using ARRAY_type = remove_cvref_t<decltype(ARRAY)>;

    static_assert(is_std_array_v<ARRAY_type>,
        "Foo requires reference to std::array of int as template argument!");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename ARRAY_type::value_type, int>,
        "Foo requires reference to std::array of int as template argument!");

    constexpr static auto N = ARRAY.size();
};

constexpr std::array<int, 3> A{1, 2, 3};
constexpr std::array<long, 3> B{1, 2, 3};
constexpr int C = 5;

void bar()
{
    Foo<A> foo_a;
    // Foo<B> foo_b; // Will give static_assert error message
    // Foo<C> foo_c; // Will give static_assert error message
}
```

In C++20 there will be concepts, which will allow you to write a concept testing the properties I am testing right now with the `static_assert`s and you will be able to use that concept in place of `auto` in the template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution pass through partial specialization

```
template <auto const &>
class Foo;

template <std::size_t N, std::array<int, N> const & ARRAY>
class Foo<ARRAY>
 { };
```

So you can write

```
constexpr std::array<int, 3> A{1, 2, 3};

int main ()
 {
    Foo<A> foo_a;
 }
```